# One sided printing in Crystal Reports - Simplex

Tags: crystal-reports

I have attached the report first 3 pages. I have a report that has a group by region. The first group and details extends to the 2nd page but I want to have 2nd-page blank and want to have it printed on the 3rd page. I need to print on an odd page on a one-sided special paper (I must not print on the back of special paper ). Means, my first page should print on special paper page1, the extended group should print on page3. Another new group should start on page5 of special paper since page 4 is blank.

Means, I need to print page1, page2 blank, then page3, page4 blank, then page5. I also need to print every new group on a new page.

I cannot control from Visual studio programmatically. Please advise it from Crystal.

I tried a lot of things already, Added this formula too. Nothing worked. Please help.

Remainder(PageNumber,2) <> 1. Thanks in advance.

[Page1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnm7U.png)

[Page2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grN7I.png)

[Page3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4j9A.png)

Comment: Have you tried controlling it with the Print Driver?  Crystal Report doesn't really provide a control for duplex/simplex settings that I'm aware of.  I've always either controlled this in a VB/C# app that uses the report, or when that can't be done I set the default settings in the installed printer's Printer Properties.

Comment: Thanks for your advise.

I cannot set the printer settings because this report fires automatically from an application upon selecting
various options and clicking print button on the application side.
I have no choice other than controlling from Crystal side.

Regards,
B